# EF Core: Which IsolationLevel to choose when creating new entry in DB?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, transactions

I have a `County` table and have this piece of code to create new entries in the table, using ASP.NET Core 6 and EF Core 6:

```
public async Task<County> Add(County entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await using (var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, cancellationToken))
    {
            var maxGroupId = await _dbContext.County.MaxAsync(c => c.GroupId, cancellationToken);

            entity.GroupId = maxGroupId + 1;

            await _dbContext.County.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);

            await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken); // --> BREAKPOINT <--
    }

    return (await _dbContext.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken)).Entity;
}
```

The idea is that every new entry should get a `GroupId` that is bigger by 1 than the previous one, so after inserting `NewCounty` and `AnotherNewCounty`, the table should look like this:

| Id | Name | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | County | 1 |
| 2 | NewCounty | 2 |
| 3 | AnotherNewCounty | 3 |

(Two entries can have the same `GroupId` with another use-case, that's why it's not just an auto-incremented value by 1, but i need to ask the db for the biggest `GroupId` every time i insert a new value.)

This works as expected with 1 instance of the application, but let's say I want to make sure that entries are added with the correct `GroupId` even if 2 people want to add a new entry at the same time. I'm trying to simulate that use-case like this:

1. I launch `instance1` of the application in debug, set the breakpoint at the `CommitAsync` (please see the code at the beginning for the breakpoint)
2. I call the endpoint by inserting a new `County` with a `Name` : `NewCounty1`
3. The execution is now at the breakpoint
4. I launch `instance2` of the application
5. I call the endpoint by inserting a new `County` with a `Name` : `NewCounty2`
6. `NewCounty2` is inserted
7. I switch to `instance1` and release the execution from the breakpoint, so `NewCounty1` is inserted

The table looks like this, both of them got the same `GroupId`, which is incorrect:

| Id | Name | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | County | 1 |
| 2 | NewCounty2 | 2 |
| 3 | NewCounty1 | 2 |

Should look like this:

| Id | Name | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | County | 1 |
| 2 | NewCounty2 | 2 |
| 3 | NewCounty1 | 3 |

I went through the different `IsolationLevel`-s when calling `BeginTransactionAsync()` but none of them works for me. I know that there is a description for them, but because of the lack of my knowledge, they are not really descriptive for me in terms of which database operations they translate to exactly.

In this use-case, i would like `instance2` to see that `instance1` already "reserved" that `GroupId` in its transaction and is locking that `GroupId` to prevent `instance2` to assign that same `GroupId` to a new `County`.

Is there something wrong with my code or it's the way that I'm trying to replicate the use case is what's wrong? Or maybe both? Thank you!

Comment: You should ***NOT*** use the `MAX() + 1` approach for this - use the proper mechanisms that your SQL Server offer : an `IDENTITY` column, or a `SEQUENCE` - then you won't have any of these issues ....

Answer (score 0):

For code first approach,try add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute on your target  property,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#explicitly-configuring-value-generation) related

two NewCounty sharing the same GroupId is the expected result for your solution due to  concurrent